# Node Nodejs Express Socket.io "Waiting for local host" "didnt send any data"

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I don't understand why my connection waits for local host and then eventually times out. I've read and reread my code a million times and now I'm stumped. Please help. It says it is listening on the port..

Also, I have redacted some of the code, but as you can see I will need my sockets, express and http running on the same port. Thank you in advance!

```
    var express = require("express");
var server = require ("http").createServer(app)
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var logger = require('morgan');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
 app.use(errorHandler());
}

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("index")
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("a user connected..");

    mongo.connect(MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
        console.log("error connecting to mongo db")
        } else {
            var collection = db.collection("chat messages")
            var stream = collection.find().sort().limit(10).stream();
            stream.on("data", function(chat) {
                console.log("emitting chat");
                socket.emit("chat", chat.content);
            });
        }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        console.log("user disconnected");
    });

 socket.on("chat", function (msg) {
        mongo.connect(MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, db) {
            if(err) {
        console.log("error");
            } else {
                var collection = db.collection("chat messages");
                collection.insert({content: msg}, function(err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("error insterting msg to database")
                    } else {
                        console.log("inserted " + msg + "to db - content")
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
        socket.broadcast.emit("chat", msg);
    }); 
});

server.listen(app.get("port"), function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    };
    console.log("listening on " + app.get("port"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something seems a bit off on your listen(), I don't see the API in server.listen() that takes a callback with the parameters of err and data. By the looks of it there are no parameters in the callback. just make it an empty anon function, are you sure you are not getting any other errors?

--edit found an issue with your mongodb collection, you are using sync not a-sync for the collection method, there is a chance that collection is undefined. do this instead

```
socket.on("chat", function(msg) {
    mongo.connect(MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
        }
        //don't do spaces in collection names - make it async with callback
        db.collection("chatmessages", function(err, col) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return;
            }
            col.insert({ content: msg}, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error insterting msg to database")
                    return;
                }
                console.log("inserted " + msg + "to db - content")
            });
        });
    });
});
```

--EDIT Below

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
//other stuff

var app = express();

//do all your app.use() here


//add all your routes here.
//so if routes where in a different file theortically
//you would have requires them in at the top like var routes = require('./routes');
//and here you would do app.use(routes);

var server = http.createServer(app);

//now you can require your io here

var io = require('socket.io')(server) //because server is now filled with all the configuration

//do you io events down below..
```

essentially when you do var app = require('express')();
it will do the same thing as
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
you're just chaining the calls together not depreciated or new.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I have edited my code so that it shows everything.

Comment: i remember there was something funny with the way you need to order of operations with Socket.io try placing the server.listen right before the socket.on('connect' line, i'll pull up a working example I have and put it in the answer

Comment: I now have my code like so: server.listen(app.get("port"), function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err)
 };
 console.log("listening on " + app.get("port"));
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
 console.log("a user connected.."); ... but unfortunately, it still does not work. hmm..

Comment: Or did you mean, I should put my server.listen within the scope of my io.on, before my server.on("disconnect") line?

Comment: no if you're getting the console.log('listening on port #'); then the server is listening correctly.. it's freezing on the collection not being async (I think)

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes and I definitely think they make more sense. However, it still doesn't load. :-(

Comment: Could you possibly push your code onto github and I'll take a look in a bit in my environment, post github link once it's uploaded.

Comment: WOW!! I figured it out! There was nothing essentially wrong with my code (although async Mongo is definitely the better practice) except the way I was requiring express. My code was var express = require("express"); and then I would set an app variable like so: var app = express(). That method is outdated and no longer works. The correct way to use express and set an app variable is: "var app = require("express")();" That subtle change allowed my server to work properly. Thank you so much for assisting me and pointing out to me the better, asynchronous use of mongo. I'm so happy! haha

Comment: ah dam I should have seen it earlier, var app = express() still works, it's the fact that you did not initialize the app before requiring the socket server. so the line right before var server = require('http')(app) <- app is not defined yet with all your properties. I really suggest 2 things going forward. 1 use typescript and 2. just require your variables normally first not passing in parameters so just do var http = require('http') <- don't call server here call it after you initialize your app. same thing with io i'll update my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: Thank you! Good to know, and I think I will become privy to typescript. Because I shouldn't allow a minor, and hard to notice detail like that to break my application for days.

Comment: Another suggestion besides typescript is to favor ES6 declarations over ES5. `var` "hoists" variable definitions to the top of the scope so that using a variable before it's actually declared and defined does not throw an error. On the other hand, ES6 `let` does not hoist, so if you try to use a variable before it's defined, it WILL throw an error, as it should. Use of Typescript is not necessary for these sort of errors, just use node version 4.x or higher.

Answer (score 1):

WOW!! I figured it out! There was nothing essentially wrong with my code (although async Mongo is definitely the better practice) except the way I was requiring express. My code was var express = require("express"); and then I would set an app variable like so: var app = express(). That method is outdated and no longer works. The correct way to use express and set an app variable is: "var app = require("express")();" That subtle change allowed my server to work properly. Thank you so much for assisting me and pointing out to me the better, asynchronous use of mongo. I'm so happy! haha EDIT: It appears, the issue is not an outdated method, rather it is the order in which I defined my app variable. "app" was being required prior to it being defined.

Comment: `var express = require("express");var app = express();` and `var app = require("express")();` are literally the same thing except that you're storing the express factory method to the variable `express`... There must have been something else you changed besides that.

Comment: That's what I believed. But it is DEFINITELY the only thing I changed, after viewing the way an app variable is set and express is required in socket.io's - site  examples. It's very odd.. OR it could be the placement of where my app variable is now called. before i required express, socket.io and all my middleware then set an app variable (as shown in my original question). Here, I have my app variable set on the first line with express required within.. Thats the only other change.. but that makes less sense to me.